# Why "theta" in this code is NaN?

Tags: matlab, neural-network, linear-regression, gradient-descent

I'm learning neural networks (linear regression) in MATLAB for my research project and this is a part of the code I use. 
The problem is the value of "theta" is NaN and I don't know why. 
Could you tell me where is the error?

```
function [theta, J_history] = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters)
theta = zeros(2, 1); % initialize fitting parameters
%GRADIENTDESCENT Performs gradient descent to learn theta
% theta = GRADIENTDESCENT(X, y, theta, alpha, num_iters) updates theta by 
% taking num_iters gradient steps with learning rate alpha
% Initialize some useful values
m = length(y); % number of training examples
J_history = zeros(num_iters, 1);
for iter = 1:num_iters
    theta = theta - ((alpha/m)*((X*theta)-y)' * X)';
end
end
% run gradient descent
theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iterations);
```

Comment: Can you provide the values of the input arguments that you give to the function?

Comment: @Cebri alpha = 0.01 and num_iters = 1500 and both of (X, y) are column vectors of 133×1

Comment: Given those input values, the line in the for loop shouldn't work. When you attempt to perform matrix multiplication between `X` (`size(X) = 133x1`) and `theta` (`size(theta) = 2x1`) you should get an `Inner matrix dimensions must agree` error. Also, why do you pass in the value of `theta` just to define it at a matrix of zeros?

Comment: @VladislavMartin I tried to play with the transpose of X and y and it gives me no error, but "theta" still has a NaN value. Could you propose a solution please? 
Theta is the parameter (weight) in the Cost function and its initial value is zero. It's adjusted with each iteration to minimize the error. 
This's not my code, I got it from an online course and I'm trying to modify it according to my application.

Comment: OK, so what are the transposes?

Comment: @MimSaad (`size(theta) = 2×1`) and (`size(X) = 133×1 = size(y)`). 
In order to multiply X and y (for example), the no. of rows of X must equal the no. of columns of y. 
I tried this form for the "theta" line:
`theta = theta - alpha * (1/m) * (X' * (X * theta - y));`
but also it gives me NaN for theta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you have is fine. But the sizes of `X` and `theta` are incompatible. In general, if `size(X)` is `[N, M]`, then `size(theta)` should be `[M, 1]`.

So I would suggest replacing the line

```
theta = zeros(2, 1);
```

with

```
theta = zeros(size(X, 2), 1);
```

should have as many columns as `theta` has elements. So in this example, `size(X)` should be `[133, 2]`.

Also, you should move that initialization before you call the function.

For example, the following code does not return `NaN` **if you remove the initialization of `theta` from the function**.

```
X = rand(133, 1); % or rand(133, 2)
y = rand(133, 1);
theta = zeros(size(X, 2), 1); % initialize fitting parameters

% run gradient descent
theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.1, 1500)
```

**EDIT**: This is in response to comments below.

Your problem is due to the gradient descent algorithm not converging. To see it yourself, plot `J_history`, which should never increase if the algorithm is stable. You can compute `J_history` by inserting the following line inside the for-loop in the function `gradientDescent`:

```
J_history(iter) = mean((X * theta - y).^2);
```

In your case (i.e. given data file and `alpha = 0.01`), `J_history` increases exponentially. This is shown in the plot below. Note that the y-axis is in logarithmic scale. 
[image: Unstable]

This is a clear sign of instability in gradient descent.

There are two ways to eliminate this problem.

**Option 1. Use smaller `alpha`**. `alpha` controls the rate of gradient descent. If it is too large, the algorithm is unstable. If it is too small, the algorithm takes a long time to reach the optimal solution. Try something like `alpha = 1e-8` and go from there. For example, `alpha = 1e-8` results in the following cost function:

[image: smaller alpha]

**Option 2. Use feature scaling** to reduce the magnitude of the inputs. One way of doing this is called [Standarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Standardization). The following is an example of using standarization and the resulting cost function:

```
data=xlsread('v & t.xlsx');
data(:,1) = (data(:,1)-mean(data(:,1)))/std(data(:,1));
```

[image: standarization]

Comment: I tried your code and it does not return `NaN` , only if I added this line before "theta" : 

`X = [ones(m,1), rand(133,1)]; % Add a column of ones to x ` 

but when I replace X and y with my values from Excel sheet it does not work and "theta" returns `NaN`. 

`X = data(:,6); y = data(:,1); X = [ones(m,1), data(:,6)]; theta = zeros(size(X, 2), 1); theta = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, 0.01, 1500); `

Could you please tell me where is the error?

Comment: Did you make sure to remove the line `theta = zeros(2, 1);` from the function `gradientDescent`? Also make sure that `X` and `y` only contain valid finite numbers. As a test, what do `var(X)` and `var(y)` return? If you require further help, you could upload the data file to Google Drive and share publicly for us to examine.

Comment: Yes, I replaced this line with yours: `theta = zeros(size(x, 2), 1);` 
`var(x) = 0  312.1246` and `var(y) = 3.7478e+05` 
I was using the line `theta = zeros(2, 1);` because I was using this line `x = [ones(m, 1), data(:, 2)]; % To add a column of ones to x` 

This is my data file, the 1st column is the velocity (km/s) and the 2nd one is the time (hours): 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw5Fgx5h69chMlMzVlNpbEd6YzA/view?usp=sharing 
I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: I tried to change the values of `alpha` and `iterations` and I found `theta` stopped return `NaN`, but I got a wrong linear regression.

Comment: The problem is due to the gradient descent algorithm diverging for your choice of data and `alpha`. See a more detailed response in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try again and check the updates.